# Limiting the total number of HTTP requests a user can make

Tags: http, web, server

How does a web server limits the total number of HTTP request rate from a ip adress? How does websites like twitter and facebook does that??

Comment: Which web server are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many pre-built module available for ip restrictions in different way.

Apache Modules :

[mod_evasive](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?page_id=442) (Focused more on reducing DoS exposure)

[mod_cband](http://dembol.org/blog/mod_cband/) (Best featured for 'normal' bandwidth control)

[mod_limitipconn](http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn.html)

[mod_bw](http://bwmod.sourceforge.net/)

[mod_bwshare](http://www.topology.org/src/bwshare/README.html)

In case of IIS 8.0 server you can use [IP and Domain Restrictions module](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions).